# Installing Node.JS on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos

I'm trying to install Node.JS on Mac OSX 10.9.3 by following the steps on [this website](http://howtonode.org/how-to-install-nodejs).

When I type the following command:

```
git clone git://github.com/ry/node.git
```

I am getting the following error:

> fatal: destination path 'node' already exists and is not an empty directory.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: ... You're cloning it into a directory that (a) already exists, and (b) isn't empty. Remove it?

Comment: @user3681670 ...you're asking how to remove a directory in OSX?

Comment: why don't you use the installer instead? http://nodejs.org/download/

Comment: well...which directory am i suppose to remove? i'll try the installer

Comment: @user3681670 I think before proceeding down the node.js path you might want to gain a basic understanding of how your computer works--it will be a great help during the rest of your explorations. Which directory?! The one it says already exists.

Comment: @DaveNewton's last comment... which probably is the one your terminal is at when running that command

Comment: Ok I think I get that...I'm now trying to confirm it worked by runnign some basic scripts but it is yielding some errors thus far..

Comment: While a downvote might be overzealous, how can this question *possibly* be upvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means there's already a folder called "node" in your current folder. Either delete it, or move to another folder and try again.

As a side comment, try installing Node (and any other software) using a package manager like [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), for easier installation/uninstallation experience.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I have the homebrew one installed, but I keep getting errors when I try running sample scripts like hello_world.js or example.js

Comment: Ok thanks again. So how can I verify the install worked correctly?

Comment: @user3681670 Start by typing `node` and see what happens.  Then, do the example on the Node.js homepage.

Comment: Type `node -v` - that should show the version of node installed, or an error if it's not.

Comment: Ok this was what the result was (shown below). What do the three periods / ellipsis mean
xxxx:bin user$ node

> Node.js homepage

...

Comment: ok I closed the terminal and just reopened it. node -v yields v0.10.28...so I think it's installed. I will close this as soon as I verify something

Answer (score 0):

**Install Node.js on Mac zsh**

**Using Homebrew:**

```
brew install node
```

**If you want to download the package with bash:**

```
curl "https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-${VERSION:-$(wget -qO- https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/ | sed -nE 's|.*>node-(.*)\.pkg</a>.*|\1|p')}.pkg" > "$HOME/Downloads/node-latest.pkg" && sudo installer -store -pkg "$HOME/Downloads/node-latest.pkg" -target "/"
```